# Could not install IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation in .netframework 4.61 API

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3, webapi, .net-framework-version

I have a **.NetFramework4.61 WebAPI**. I am trying install **IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation** & **System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt** using Nuget but it is giving me the below error. I also try to install using package manager console that too also failed

```
>Install-Package IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation -Version 2.14.0
>Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 6.11.0
```

How to resolve this issue?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception 'System.AggregateException' thrown when trying to add source 'http://172.16.20.241:11688/codeengines/nuget/'. Please verify all your online package sources are available.
One or more errors occurred.
Unable to load the service index for source http://172.16.20.241:11688/codeengines/nuget/.
An error occurred while sending the request.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.16.20.241:11688

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be lack of nuget source issue and you need to add the nuget source for nuget.org and then try to install the package

1. Add a nuget source point to https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json on visual studio

[image]

2. Install the package again. You can select the package source on package management console on visual studio or specify it in the command as bellow:

```
PS> Install-Package IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation -Version 2.14.0 -Source nuget.org
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My issue was not connected to the VPN so download from nuget was not working.